# Mixed Language documentation generation in Xcode Framework

Tags: ios, documentation-generation, xcode13, docc

I have created a sample objective c framework in Xcode where I also created a swift file. This is the navigation controller showing one swift file and another objective c class (NewFramework).

When I try to build documentation for the framework, I will only get documentation for the swift file and not for the objective c class.
Here is the ObjcTemp.h file contents:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ObjcTemp : NSObject

@property int val;

-(void)printHello;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

And here is the ObjcTemp.m file contents:

```
#import "ObjcTemp.h"

@implementation ObjcTemp

-(void)printHello{
    printf("Hello World!");
}

@end
```

I used default xcode 13 documentation tool (DocC).
[image: Build Documentation]

The resulting generated documentation archive is like below:
.
[image]

I want to generate complete documentation both for objective c and swift files using Default Xcode documentation tool. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocC in Xcode 13 is only able to build documentation for Swift code.

Support for building documentation for Objective-C code was [added in Xcode 14](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes):

> ### Documentation
>
> ##### New Features
>
> - Swift-DocC in Xcode now supports writing and building documentation for Objective-C and C APIs